# Get rid of wildcard parameter in return value

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

I have some code which makes use of generics internally. Everything is fine so far, until the point where functionality is exposed via a public API. The problem is identical to the following toy example: I have a `List` of wrapped items with a specific subtype (`T extends Number` in this example). When I want to return this `List`, I am currently returning a `List<Wrapper<? extends Number>>` which makes client code very verbose.

Is there a possibility of changing the return type to `List<Wrapper<Number>>`? Clients do not need to know, that Wrappers contain any specific type of Number. I tried several approaches with casting, but they all fail with compile errors.

```
public static List<Wrapper<? extends Number>> getNumbers() {
    Wrapper<Integer> number1 = new Wrapper<Integer>(1);
    Wrapper<Double> number2 = new Wrapper<Double>(2.);

    List<Wrapper<? extends Number>> numbers = new ArrayList<Wrapper<? extends Number>>();
    numbers.add(number1);
    numbers.add(number2);
    return numbers;
}

class Wrapper<T extends Number> {
    private final T item;
    Wrapper(T item) {
        this.item = item;
    }
    T getItem() {
        return item;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on what you have shown about your `Wrapper` type, `Wrapper<? extends Number>` is *exactly* what you want for your case, since it is only possible to get items out of your `Wrapper` (it is a producer), and not possible to put items in. So when you call `getItem()` on a `Wrapper<? extends Number>`, it returns a `Number`, which is what you want. How does it not fit your need?

"Verbose" is not a legitimate reason to not throw away type safety.

Comment: In my case I am not using `Number` but subtypes of a specific type in my library. Via API I do not want to expose the fact, that these subtypes exist, but the `? extends` exactly suggests that. Keeping code short and readable is definitely a goal, but I agree on the "producer" aspect. I understand that it is "cheating", but could you hilight the actual implications? Another solution seems to be to "re-wrap" all items in `numbers` into a newly created `Wrapper<Number>` but is this really different?

Comment: +1.  The OP should change the client code...or even better, avoid this abuse of generics at all...

Comment: @qqilihq: `? extends X` means either `X` or its subtype. It does not necessarily imply that there exists subtypes of `X`. For example, you could write `? extends String` but there cannot be any subtypes of String. From a generics point of view, you should use `? extends` because nothing in your code depends on the type parameter being exactly that type.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge it is not possible if you want to return T. You cannot return a subtype of T when you want to return T

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that the following approach works. Any feedback and comments about potential pitfalls still very appreciated.

```
public static List<Wrapper<Number>> getNumbers() {
    Wrapper<Integer> number1 = new Wrapper<Integer>(1);
    Wrapper<Double> number2 = new Wrapper<Double>(2.);
    List<Wrapper<? extends Number>> numbers = new ArrayList<Wrapper<? extends Number>>();
    numbers.add(number1);
    numbers.add(number2);
    return (List<Wrapper<Number>>)(List<?>)numbers;
}
```

Comment: This is wrong. A `Wrapper<Integer>` is not a `Wrapper<Number>`, even though an `Integer` is a `Number`. So what you are doing is lying to the type system.

Comment: Also, if you are going to do this, why not just declare `number1` and `number2` to be `Wrapper<Number>`? Then you wouldn't need to do any crazy casting.